# How to store +4000 user preferences in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I really don't know how to set this DB up.

I have a list of 10k users.

Each one needs to have +4000 boolean data.

I'm confused as to how I should store these because I would need to split them in php and work with them often in the pages.

Thanks.

Comment: 1. Store them as key/value in a DB. With proper indexing on user ID and key retrieval should be very fast across 40M rows. 2. Fix whatever monstrosity requires you to have 4,000 configurations per user. Who on earth is setting 4,000 different config settings to use your app?

Comment: Seriously, over 4000 preferences?  Have you grouped them?  That might help with managing them all.

Comment: That is quite a bit of preferences.  I would suggest start by logically breaking the preferences down in to smaller tables that are categorized.  4000+ fields in a result set may pose an issue when fetching data.

Comment: MySQL is perfectly capable of storing 4000 rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simplest solution (but not the best one) is to store them as long string (varchar/text type) where each symbol corresponds to some boolean value, so you will have something like `'010101010101010'`, note - you should use binary char with ascii encoding

so you will be able to work with these data like `$string[$someIndex]`

another approach: store it as long bit mask - this will take 8 times less amount of memory (blob type)

3rd variant: store them in table like `id_user, id_preference, bitvalue`, each row - one preference for one user

4th variant: reconsider your application - there is no sense in 4000+ preferences for each user :)

Comment: Before sending the binary string to mysql, could I use bindec() to convert it to decimal so it's a shorter varchar ? And obviously, do it the other way around as well.

Comment: @injurer001 no, you do not need to use bindec, just plain string with ones and zeros

Comment: i will take you take and store it as long bit mask. thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You can [`serialize`](http://php.net/serialize) the data and store it in a `TEXT` in SQL, and then [`unserialize`](http://php.net/unserialize) the data and store it in your `$_SESSION`

Answer (score 0):

create table user_prefs (
  user_id int,
  prefs varchar(4000));

Each char is a single preference.

in php(or something like this using MDB2):

```
    $res = $db->query("select * from user_prefs where user_id=$user_id");
    $row = $res->fetchRow();
    $user_prefs = $row[1];
    //now your $user_prefs[i] is the ith preference.
```